# Celery 4: How to write logs to syslog

Tags: django, celery, syslog

I'm trying to send Celery's workers logs to SysLog. Somebody can help me how to achieve that?

Thanks a lot!

I tried with this text: http://oriolrius.cat/blog/2013/09/06/celery-logs-through-syslog/

But only logs the prints to syslog. Cant use getLogger of python.